# Figure reference micro

Tags: cross-referencing

I want to use `\autoref(figure)` to produce

> Figure 1.1 shows us blah blah blah

and make a micro for something like `\figref(figure)` to produce

> Blah Blah Blah is shown in figure 2.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cleveref does this automagically:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[noabbrev]{cleveref}

\begin{document}

\chapter{title}

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics{example-image}
\caption{content...}
\label{foo}
\end{figure}


\Cref{foo} shows us blah blah blah

Blah Blah Blah is shown in \cref{foo}

\end{document}
```

[image]